# Desktop does not show icons

Tags: nautilus, icons

Since this morning, I have some files in the desktop, but I cannot see them. I know nothing has been deleted, as

I can see what's on the desktop whenever I try to save anything from the Internet. How could I make the documents visible again? It's even stranger the fact that I cannot see anything I had yesterday (except for a shortcut), but I can see documents I save there today. Thank you.

Comment: Can you find your documents in the Dash? (Press the Super key and start typing your document's title)

Comment: Have you gone from automatically saving documents to the desktop, Home->Desktop, to saving them automatically at the usual place, Home->Downloads?

Answer (score 5):

Do

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Open `Advanced settings` from Dash .Then Slide the **ON** option to `have file manager handle the desktop`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To access the files you can always go to `/home/username/Desktop`, where username is your user name.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the empty space on the desktop and check "Keep aligned". This should realign all the icons if they are somewhere outside the screen.

Try to use other folders for saving stuff. When the Desktop folder gets crowded it's really hard to find thing.
You can organise everything in folders on the desktop if you thing it is easier to access them.

Comment: This is unlikely to help, because *newly saved files* on the Desktop are very unlikely to be outside of the screen, if there is unoccupied space on the desktop within the viewable area.

Comment: I use a dual monitor setup with different screen resolutions and this happens frequently.